# Quadratic modular equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers and $a = n + 1 - \varphi(n)$. Then what are the roots of the equation:

$$x^2 + ax + n = 0 \ (mod \ n)$$

Any help with this ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ so $x^2 + ax + n = 0 \ (mod \ n) \iff x^2 + (2-p-q)x = 0 \ (mod \ n)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: we have $x^2+ax+n\equiv x^2+ax\equiv x(x+a)\bmod n$. Hence certainly $x=0$ and $x=-a$ are roots in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n$. We can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find all roots, by first finding all roots modulo $p$, and then modulo $q$. Since $p,q$ are primes, a quadratic equation over the fields $\mathbb{Z}/p$ resp. over $\mathbb{Z}/q$ can have at most two roots.